# In Vim, prevent a plugin from opening a file in a specific window

Tags: vim, taglist

I'm using vim (gvim actually) with two plugins, [Project.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) and [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273).
When I double click on an entry of a plugin's window, such as a tag from taglist, the currenlty selected window is set to the file containing that tag.

How ever, when the curently open window is Project's, the window goes to editing a file and I loose my project window.
Is there a way to lock the editing of a file in a plugin-based window ? For eg do nothing, or open it in the last "regular" window active.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to overcome this problem would be to `:set switchbuf+=split` in your `.vimrc`; this would cause new buffers to be opened in splits. Check out `:help 'switchbuf'` for more info, you can tweak the behaviour.

If you don't want vim to behave that way all the time, there are commands to jump to tags and such in new splits, tabs, etc., like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, which opens the tag under the cursor in a new split. See `:help window-tag` for details.